# CMake Include-Dependencies for Projects

Tags: c++, msbuild, cmake

i'm trying to switch from a large Visual Studio-based project (with static, dynamic libraries, executables) to CMake. It would work well, but as many of the static libraries have export libraries (without the need of linking the library to the project), i need a way to include project's **interfaces** only ***without*** linking the static library.

Situation:

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Test)

add_subdirectory(Projekt_B)
add_subdirectory(Projekt_A)
```

#### Projekt_A/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Projekt_A 
    libraryContent.cpp
    libHeader.h
    libInterfaceOnly.h)

target_include_directories(Projekt_A PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})  
# could be **INTERFACE** as well
```

#### Projekt_B/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Projekt_B_Public SHARED
    libraryContentB.cpp
    libHeaderB.h
)

add_library(Projekt_B_Private SHARED
    libraryContentB.cpp
    libHeaderB.h
)

add_library(Projekt_B_Interface SHARED
    libraryContentB.cpp
    libHeaderB.h
)

## this Line works but links Projekt_A 
target_link_libraries(Projekt_B_Public PUBLIC Projekt_A)

## this Line works too, but links Projekt_A to it without passing them on
target_link_libraries(Projekt_B_Private PRIVATE Projekt_A)

## this Line works **only** if no interface of A is used in B
target_link_libraries(Projekt_B_Interface INTERFACE Projekt_A)
```

So, all targets compile when **no** interface of **Projekt_A** was used in **Projekt_B_**. When I include a header (which has been exported via **traget_include_directories**), **Projekt_B_Interface** won't link anymore.

MsBuild tells for **Projekt_B_Interface**:

```
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\CL.exe 
  /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D 
  "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D Projekt_B_Interface_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D 
  _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope 
  /Fo"Projekt_B_Interface.dir\Debug\\" 
  /Fd"Projekt_B_Interface.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue 
  D:\Develop\CMake\TEST\Projekt_B\libr.c    
  libr.c
D:\Develop\CMake\TEST\Projekt_B\libr.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 
'libinc.h': No such file or directory      
[D:\Develop\CMake\TEST\build\Projekt_B\Projekt_B_Interface.vcxproj]
```

Within the other **Projekt_B_*** projects it's successfull:

```
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\CL.exe 
  /c /ID:\Develop\CMake\TEST\Projekt_A /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D 
  WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" 
  /D Projekt_B_Public_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS 
  /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Projekt_B_Public.dir\Debug\\" 
  /Fd"Projekt_B_Public.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue 
  D:\Develop\CMake\TEST\Projekt_B\libr.c
  libr.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe 
  /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\Develop\CMake\TEST\build\
  Projekt_B\Debug\Projekt_B_Public.dll" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO 
  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib
  oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib 
  ..\Projekt_A\Debug\Projekt_A.lib /MANIFEST 
  /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG
  /PDB:"D:/Develop/CMake/TEST/build/Projekt_B/Debug/Projekt_B_Public.pdb" 
  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT     
  /IMPLIB:"D:/Develop/CMake/TEST/build/Projekt_B/Debug/Projekt_B_Public.lib" 
  /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /debug /DLL Projekt_B_Public.dir\Debug\libr.obj
  Projekt_B_Public.vcxproj -> D:\Develop\CMake\TEST\build\Projekt_B\Debug\
  Projekt_B_Public.dll
```

Any ideas how I could get something like:

```
target_compile_libraries(Projekt_B HEADERS Projekt_A)
```

(something that ***target_include_directoies*** would sound like...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution for this situation (without the need of settings vars in CMake):

#### Projekt_A/CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
# create a interface
add_library(IProjekt_A INTERFACE)

# add *export* headers to interface
target_include_directories(IProjekt_A INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# bind interface to project itself (just in case)
target_link_libraries(Projekt_A INTERFACE IProjekt_A)
```

#### Projekt_B/CMakeLists.txt

```
...
# this will add includes *only* and reexports them within Projekt_B
target_link_libraries(Projekt_B PUBLIC IProjekt_A)

# this will add includes and library for link and reexport
target_link_libraries(Projekt_B PUBLIC Projekt_A)

# this will only add the includes for *this* project
target_link_libraries(Projekt_B PRIVATE IProjekt_A)
```

This makes it possible to export the headers **in** the build environment. Very usefull in large projects.

I'll hope it helps someone else either!

Cheers.